# How do I create a Fedora Remix SD card?

Tags: operating-systems, sd-card

On MacOS, I can't run the Fedora installer python script as there are too many unsatisfied dependencies that are not easy to install (e.g. PyQt).

Rather than troubleshooting how to install python libraries on my Mac, I'd like simple pointer to the Fedora disk images and instructions on how to write these using dd (as per the other RPi distros).

Comment: Info about Fedora Remix is here: http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/805

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of writing, this is not possible. The [Remix's Wiki](http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/wiki/index.php/Raspberry_Pi_Fedora_Remix) says that you can download the image from the Foundation's website. However, it has been removed since the original image was buggy, with the recommendation that you use the Debian image instead.

Comment: I can't find a source for why the image was removed. Anyone?